# Deny access of files via browser

Tags: php

I am creating files with PHP:

```
 $handle = fopen('backup/db-'.date("ymdhis").'.sql.gz','w+');
 fwrite($handle, $gzdata);
 fclose($handle);
 chmod('backup/db-'.date("ymdhis").'.sql.gz', 0700);
```

but the created file is accessible via web browser. Is here some way to not allow that?

Answer (score 0):

Add your `.htaccess` file

```
 <FilesMatch "\.(inc)$">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Also good advice: put your includes in a directory and deny access to that directory in your `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways:
if you must use public space address, protect it writing also an apropiate "deny" on .htaccess
on the other hand, put it on a private space